# My app in landscape When i back my flutter webview

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutter-web

I have created Flutter Webview for the game. game is working on landscape mood. Webview also shows landscape but when I back the Webview app also showed in landscape mood

[image: tt]

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not changing the system view after the game screen.
Try anyone of the following,

1.Add this in the .then(){} call back of the navigation call to the          gmescreen,

```
   SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
     ]);
```

OR

2.Add this at the dispose method of game screen,

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I have added only  DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,

  DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, because I need the webview in landscape . but when I back the webview app also in landscape mood I need to fix that